# Load up multiple remote data sources for knockout.js data binding

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js, viewmodel

I'm working on a knockout.js wizard and need to get data from multiple remote data sources (via AJAX) before I can properly render the drop-down menus in the wizard.

Additionally, there are 4 dropdowns and while #1 and #2 can be loaded up first, #3 and #4 depend on the choices selected in the first two.

So far I've experimented with using jQuery promises and also just nesting data calls and their associated callbacks, but are there any better ways to structure my view model code for the wizard?

Below is some of the data loading code. I'm happy to provide more if needed.

```
var postobj = {
    id: workoutId
};
var getWorkout = $.post("./RowingWorkouts/GetWorkoutUsingId", postobj);
var getDiet = $.post("./Diet/GetDietUsingId", postobj);
var getFeedback = $.post("./RowingWorkouts/GetWorkoutFeedback", postobj);
// When all three are successful - I haven't gotten the when syntax to actually work yet
$.when(getWorkout, getDiet, getFeedback).done(function (workout, diet, feedback) {
    //each of the parameter is an array
    renderCharts(workout[0], diet[0], feedback[0])
    // Here are more dropdowns that depend on the choices from the above ones
    self.suggestedWorkouts = ko.observableArray();
    // pseudo-code for data call for getting suggested workouts
    $.post("./RowingWorkouts/GetSuggested", { id: selectedOldWorkout }, function(result) { 
        self.suggestedWorkouts(result);
    });

});
```

This goes several levels deeper, and I would prefer avoiding it if at all possible. Are there any design patterns I'm missing or is this plain coded wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [lazy loading observable](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/lazy-loading-observable-in-knockoutjs.html) to get data into your viewModel observables, and computed to subscribe on load of the parent level observables.

```
function ViewModel() {
   this.workout = ko.onDemandObservable(ViewModel.prototype.getWorkout, this);
   this.diet = ko.onDemandObservable(ViewModel.prototype.getDiet, this);
   this.feedback= ko.onDemandObservable(ViewModel.prototype.getFeedback, this);
   this.suggestedWorkouts = ko.observable();

   ko.computed(ViewModel.prototype.listsLoaded, this);
}

ViewModel.prototype.listsLoaded= function () {    
   if (this.workout.loaded() && this.diet.loaded() && this.feedback.loaded()) {
        this.loadSuggestedWorkouts();
   }
}

ViewModel.prototype.getWorkout = function () {
   ...
}

ViewModel.prototype.getDiet = function () {
   ...
}

ViewModel.prototype.getFeedback = function () {
   ...
}

ViewModel.prototype.loadSuggestedWorkouts = function () {
  ...
}
```